# Are there identities which will make calculating $\Delta \frac{e^{ik|x|}}{|x|}$ more efficient and clearer?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, operator-theory, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions

Let $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am trying to calculate

$$\Delta \frac{e^{ik|x|}}{|x|}$$

Doing this 'manually' be calculating second derivatives is really long and tedious due to the Euclidean distance function $|\cdot|$. Is there some identities that can be used to make it more efficient, and clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spherical polar coordinates. Your function becomes $\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}$ with $r \in \mathbb{R}.$ And it is well known that $$\Delta f =\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}) + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin \varphi} \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}(\sin \varphi \frac{\partial f}{\partial \varphi}) + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2 \varphi} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2}.$$ You will only have to compute the first term.

Comment: This is in 3 dimensions. Maybe spherical polar coordinates might help him a bit.

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Comment: @C.Dubussy Thanks. As expected it came out as $-k^2 \Delta \frac{e^{ik|x|}}{|x|}$. I wonder if there are other identities for it...considering how cleanly it ends up?

Comment: Well an other formula is $$\Delta ( fg ) = ( \Delta f ) \,g + 2 \cdot( \nabla f ) \cdot ( \nabla g ) + f( \Delta g )$$ which you can use with $f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|}$ and $g(x) = e^{ik|x|}$ but I'm pretty sure this is not faster.